# presentModalViewController translucent with previous view in the background

Tags: objective-c, ios, uikit

Im trying to present a view translucently and that the previous view sticks around and be that its visible in the background.

I've got

```
[self presentModalViewController:modalView animation:YES];
```

and I have the transparency set in the modalView's viewDidLoad, but after modalView gets brought up the previous view disappears. What can I do to keep the other view to stay around in the background?

I have also tried adding it with

```
[self.view addSubview:modalView.view];
```

It doesn't cover the whole screen, I would like to be able to solve this problem using presentModalViewController method.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just want a view to be displayed on top of your main view. Modal views are a finicky way of presenting subviews, instead you should look at creating a simple view class to add to your view controller. You can then use [UIView animate...]; method to animate it in and out of view.

To get you started:

```
- (void)displayViewButtonPressed(id)sender
{

    if (!self.topView)
    {
        UIView *overlayView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(44.0f, 22.0f, 40.0f, 44.0f];
        [overlayView setAlpha:0.0f];
        [overlayView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        [self setTopView:overlayView];
        [overlayView release];
    }

    [self.view addSubView:self.topView];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
            animations:^{

                [self.topView setAlpha:1.0f];
            }];
}
```

In the above method we create a custom UIView and animate it into position. We maintain a pointer to it so we can remove it later (like so:)

```
- (void)dismissViewButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
            animations:^{
                [self.topview setAlpha:0.0f];
            }
            completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                [self.topView removeFromSuperView];
            }
}
```

Its a little more work that using modal views, but it gives you much more flexibility in regards to what you use and how you display it.

Hope this helps:)

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it out with my code and let you know if it works